# Using static arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I have problem with arrays. For example I have `2 4 5` in array `tab1` and I have to copy them to `tab2`.
The size of array `tab2` is e.g. 10 and the `tab2` has to hold `2 4 5 2 4 5 2 4 5 2`. I guess I have problem in  `printf()` in main loop but I have no idea where. Can you help somehow? Thanks in advance.

```
for (int j = 0; j <= b;j += a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a;)
    {
        tab2[i] = tab1[i];
        i++;
    }
    c = b - j;
    if (c < a)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < c;)
        {
            tab2[i] = tab1[i];
            printf("%d", tab2[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    else
    printf("%d", tab2[j]);
}
```

Comment: C# and printf are in two different worlds.

Comment: Please show the definition of `tab1` and `tab2`; furthermore the code seems to be C rather than C#. How does the actual behavior differ from the expected behaviour?

Comment: Doesn't looks like a c# syntax to me.

Comment: int tab1[10];
int tab2[500];
int a, b, c ;

Comment: don't add the code in comment. edit your question and add the relevant code there.

Comment: For a basic idea: set an index variable (`j`) for the source array (`tab1`) to zero, then got through each index (`i`) of destination array (`tab2`), inside that loop, set `tab2[i] = tab1[j]` and increment `j`. And if `j` is at end of `tab1`, set it back to zero and continue.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

```
int tab1[N];
int tab2[M];
```

(and `tab1` initialized already) you might do

```
int i;

// copy
for(i=0; i<M; i++)
    tab2[i] = tab1[i % N];

// test
for(i=0; i<M; i++)
    printf("%d ", tab2[i]);
printf("\n");
```

Comment: superb !! just mention, `M > N`

Comment: Thanks, It is working now. What actualy '%' in tab[i % N] do?

Comment: @balerofon - `%` is the [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator, which gives you the remainder of an integer division.

Comment: @SouravGhosh No, `M > N` follows from the problem description, but it is not necessary. If `M <= N` the code would also work fine, just filling `tab2` with (a part of) `tab1`.

Comment: Same. I should have said `in accordance to OP's description`. :-)